# throws noSuchMethodError in MapStruct

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have a boolean and an enum defined in my entity and my dto

```
@Entity
public class ConfigurationItemEntity {

    @Id
    private String externalId;

    private ConfigurationTypeEnum configurationType;

    private boolean active;

    public String getExternalId() {
       return externalId;
    }

    public void setExternalId(String externalId) {
       this.externalId = externalId;
    }

    public ConfigurationType getConfigurationType() {
       return configurationType;
    }

    public void setConfigurationType(ConfigurationType configurationType) {
       this.configurationType = configurationType;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
       return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
       this.active = active;
    }

}

public class ConfigurationItem {

    private String externalId;

    private ConfigurationTypeEnum configurationType;

    private boolean active;
}
```

I wan to map the dto to entity

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ConfigurationItemMapper {

    ConfigurationItemEntity configItemDomainToConfigItemEntity(ConfigurationItem configurationItem);

}
```

but i get this error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.xx.mapper.ConfigurationItemMapper.configItemDomainToConfigItemEntity(Lcom/xx/uc/health/administration/ConfigurationItem;)Lcom/xx/entities/ConfigurationItemEntity;

Comment: did you makes `mvn clean install` before running your app?

Comment: Looks like the mapper generated by MapStruct (should be ConfigurationItemMapperImpl by default) do not have the implementation of this method which is unusual. You can check for the implementation class that MapStruct generated by either decoding the jar file OR even better within the IDE that you are using for development. The source is generated as soon as you perform maven install (assuming you are using maven). If the file doesn't have this method than look out for error/warning messages during maven install to find clue what's wrong and adjust MapStruct config accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

According to MapStruct documentation

> MapStruct is an annotation processor which is plugged into the Java compiler and can be used in command-line builds (Maven, Gradle etc.) as well as from within your preferred IDE.

It works during the `compile` phase of maven lifecycle, so make sure that you run `mvn clean compile` before using it. You may validate the generated mapper by looking at `target/generated-sources` (This is where they get generated by default)